# How to save child object in parent class object using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Child object is not saved in parent class object getting error.

In parent and child class contains all values but saving time getting error
`session.save(parent)` getting an error as I mentioned.

Parent class

```
@Table(name = "Parent")
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "parentId")
    private Long parentId;

    // parent to child
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
    @JsonIgnore 
    private ListChild> childList ;


Child class

@Entity
@Table(name="Child")
public class Child{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="childId")
    private Long childId;   

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId" ,insertable=false, updatable=false,nullable=false)
    private Parent parent;
```

Error is:

```
   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.tta.abcd.model.Child]
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2345)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2852)
        at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:713)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:697)
        at com.tta.abcd.DAO.ProduceDAO.saveProduce(ProduceDAO.java:61)
        at com.tta.abcd.service.ProduceServiceImpl.saveProduce(ProduceServiceImpl.java:23)
        at com.tta.abcd.service.ProduceServiceImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$a6eaa4a0.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:639)
        at com.tta.abcd.service.ProduceServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$79bed302.saveProduce(<generated>)
        at com.tta.abcd.controller.ProduceController.saveProduce(ProduceController.java:138)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:747)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:688)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:946)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:848)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'parentId' doesn't have a default value
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2427)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2345)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2330)
        at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
        ... 60 more
```

Comment: You shoud really search on google, or even better, on SO, as this question has already been asked many times!! And moreover, everything you need to answer your question is written in the stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the parent field on the child as updatable and nullable true.

Hibernate adds child entries with join column null, and then it issues updates to the entry.

Since it is the responsibility of the parent object to insert child elements then set insertable,updatable,nullable to true.

Comment: thank you, now the values are saving into db.but parentId is set to null

Comment: set updatable to true

Answer (score 0):

The parentId column is not nullable, so the parent field of each child must be set before you save.